# How to access resources directly in S3 from Amazon beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java application deployed at elastic beanstalk tomcat and the purpose of the application is to serve resources from S3 in zipped bundles. For instance I have 30 audio files that I zip up and return in the response.

I've used the getObject request from the AWS SDK, however its super slow, I assume it's requesting each object over the network. Is it possible to access the S3 resources directly? The bucket with my resources is located next to the beanstalk bucket.

Comment: Did you ensure your bucket and Beanstalk are in the same region ? All requests will happen on network - Though the bucket which stores beanstalk app is next to your data bucket, the application "runs" on another server.

Comment: Yeah they are both in the same region region=us-east-1

Comment: Did you consider keeping the files pre-zipped on S3 and serving from S3 directly using signed URL: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html

Comment: That could work out too, however as it turns out even though I have fair number of files, the different zip bundle variations are fairly limited so I just implemented S3 memory cache for my app. I'll see how that works and if it doesn't I'll move into the pre-zipping. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Updating in the answer for future reference by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer from S3 to EC2 is fast, if they are in the same region.

If you still want faster (and reliable) delivery of files, consider keeping files pre-zipped on S3 and serve from S3 directly rather than going through your server. You can use [signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html) scheme here, so that the bucket need not be public.

Next level is speed up is by keeping the S3 behind Cloudfront as an origin server. Here the files are cached in locations near your users. [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)